# fitoption cleared inside parfor?

Tags: matlab, parfor

I'm trying to speedup the fit of a large amount of data with MATLAB by using parallelism, and I'm facing quite a strange problem.

I tried to isolate the problem hoping someone might have a clue about what's happening. Here's the sample code:

```
f = @(a, x) a*x;
fitopt = fitoptions(f);

for i = 1:5
  disp(fitopt);
end
```

If I run the code above, the contents of `fitopt` will be written 5 times as expected. However, if I replace the `for` by a `parfor` loop, `fitopt` is set to empty and nothing is displayed.

Any clue what could be going wrong?

My config: MATLAB 2014a on windows 7, 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following is based on MATLAB version R2016b...*

As best as I can tell, this appears to be an issue with MATLAB's ability to correctly [broadcast](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/broadcast-variable.html) (or not) certain class objects to the [`parfor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) workers. The [`fitoptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fitoptions.html) function returns an object of class `curvefit.nlsqoptions` in your example. Going through the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/index.html) code, one can see that these objects are still defined using an older UDD class system (a good introduction by Donn Shull can be found on [Undocumented MATLAB](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/introduction-to-udd)). Although the newer [MCOS](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/object-oriented-programming.html) (MATLAB Class Object System) was introduced many years ago, you can still find a number of objects defined using UDD.

In your example, `fitopt` should be [broadcast](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/broadcast-variable.html) (i.e. copied) to each of the workers, but instead `fitopt` is set to `[]` within the `parfor` loop. If we try this with another class object defined using the newer class system (like those created by [`fittype`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html)), then the broadcasting works fine. For example, this test code:

```
f = @(a, x) a*x;
uddObj = fitoptions(f);
mcosObj = fittype(f);

parfor i = 1:3
  fprintf('\nWorker %d:\n', i);
  uddObj
  mcosObj
end
```

produces this output:

```
Worker 2:

uddObj =
     []

mcosObj = 
     General model:
     mcosObj(a,x) = a*x

Worker 1:

uddObj =
     []

mcosObj = 
     General model:
     mcosObj(a,x) = a*x

Worker 3:

uddObj =
     []

mcosObj = 
     General model:
     mcosObj(a,x) = a*x
```

So, in short, it appears that `parfor` loops can't correctly broadcast UDD style objects. One workaround would be to create these objects within the parfor loop, avoiding the broadcasting:

```
f = @(a, x) a*x;

parfor i = 1:5
  fitopt = fitoptions(f);  % Function handle f broadcasts just fine
  disp(fitopt);
end
```

You could also create a [sliced variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html) by creating an array of objects that you index into:

```
f = @(a, x) a*x;
fitopt = repmat(fitoptions(f), [1 5]);

parfor i = 1:5
  disp(fitopt(i));
end
```

Comment: yes, I can confirm it works. I prepared a list of fitopt and used them in the loop. thank you for your help!